# Adding a Variable to a Pre-Populated Tweet

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter, tweets

I'm adding a Tweet button to a webpage, and while Twitter gives a fairly straightforward way to customize the tweet and generate the button, so as to simply copy and paste the code into a webpage, I would like even more customization.

The app is built in Rails, and I would like for the tweet to dynamically include the Twitter handle (if available) for the variable.

The current code to generate the Twitter button is the following:

```
<% if @job.twitter.present? %>
<li><%= link_to '<i class="fi-social-twitter"></i> '.html_safe + " Job News", twitter_url(@job.twitter), :target => '_blank' %></li>
```

Using Twitter's [tweet button tool](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet), I created:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Check out this job!" data-via="BigAmazingJobs" data-hashtags="JobTag">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

The tweet button functions just fine, pre-populated with the site's main Twitter handle and the proper hashtag, but I'd like to add the Twitter handle associated with the particular `@job` variable.

I've scoured the Twitter Developer documentation for [Tweet Web Intent](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent) and [Tweet Button](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button), but I've come up short.

Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the handle to the `data-text` property on the a-tag. Like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
   <%# Conditionally add "@@job.twitter" %>
   data-text="Check out this job<% if @job.twitter.present? %><%= "@{@job.twitter}" %><% end %>!"
   data-via="BigAmazingJobs" data-hashtags="JobTag">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```